# Run Event Macro from a particular Sub

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a module with a lot of sub's:

```
Sub a1
Sub a2
Sub a3
...
Sub a10
```

And in the worksheet, I have a Event Macro:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
...
End Sub
```

Sub a1 to a9 makes changes in the worksheet (add columns, change values...)

I wish that the event macro starts to work when a1-a9 it will be done (only for a10).
Is this posible?

Comment: Look into the `Application.EnableEvents` function.  You can then toggle whether the Worksheet event fires or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add in logic branching to your event change macro, so that it checks for a certain parameter before it runs. First, make a Global Boolean variable, which either holds True or False - then make your sub A9 switch it to True. For example:

```
Global Start_Event_Code as Boolean

Sub A9
    'Other Code
    Start_Event_Code = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Start_Event_Code Then
        'Do stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you could make it so that the A10 sub switches it off again:

```
Sub A9
    Start_Event_Code = False
    'Other Code
End Sub
```

Comment: Uooo! Really intelligent method! I will try it! Thanks